# How to extract everything in a sublist without knowing how many object there are? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

How can I extract every item in a sublist without knowing how many items there are in a particular sublist?

I'm trying to print out all the word in a text file, so I created a list like a list:

```
file=open("a_file.txt")
word=[line.strip().split('\t') for line in file]
```

when I print out word, I get the list of word, with only one sublist with all the items I want in it, like this:

```
[["a", "b", "c"........]]
```

but I want the list to be like this:

```
['a','b','c',.......]
```

So I guess my question is, is it possible to extract all the items in a sublist?

and since I don't know how many items there are in the sublist, and I want all of the items instead of one of them, which is why I assume that I can't use a method like "sublist = lst[0]", so is there another way??

Comment: If you have `lst = [["a", "b", "c"........]]`, you can use `sublist = lst[0]`. Is that what you need? If no, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50236863/edit) to include explicitly what you want. Also include generic `[python]` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
file=open("a_file.txt")
word_list=[line.strip().split('\t') for line in file]
for sub_list in word_list:
    for word in sub_list:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, it's my first post here. There shouldn't be empty lines. My first attempt had everything on two lines.

Comment: I edited it for you.  The trick is to have 4 spaces at the beginning of each line you want to be code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **nested for-loop** inside the list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
word=[x for line in file for x in line.strip().split('\t')]
```